# Can I iterate through an vector of variable names in an R For Loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

##### Background:

I'm building a complex function which, in part, creates groups of heterogeneous size and assigns homogenous values to members of each group. To make writing the larger, more complex function simpler, I built this simple function which will allow me to do what I described and it works exactly as I need it to. To demonstrate its effects:

```
## Chunky4Loop.R | v1.0 - 2022.01.01

# A function that allows us to take a small number of values from an array of any size 
# and paste them into a dataframe in chunks, which may or may not be equal in size 
Chunky4Loop <-function(chunk, # Value noting how many chunks to iterate through. The value of chunk should be equal to the length of the arrays Quantity and Input
                       quantity, # Vectors noting the size of, or how many rows are contained within, each chunk
                       input) # The values that each chunk should take
{LoopTracker <- 0
output <- NA
for (i in 1:chunk){
  if (i == 1){
    output[1:quantity[i]] <- rep(input[i], quantity[i])
    LoopTracker <- LoopTracker + quantity[i]
  }
  if (i > 1){
    output[(LoopTracker + 1):(LoopTracker + quantity[i])] <- rep(input[i], quantity[i])
    LoopTracker <- LoopTracker + quantity[i]
  }
}
rm(LoopTracker, i)
df
return(output)
}

nGroups <- 3
nPeople <- c(7,3,1)
GroupName <- c("A","B","C")

rows <- 1:sum(nPeople)
cols <- c("Group", "ATK", "DMG")
(df <- data.frame(matrix(NA, 
                        nrow = length(rows), 
                        ncol = length(cols), 
                        dimnames = list(rows, cols))))
#   Group ATK DMG
#1    NA  NA  NA
#2    NA  NA  NA
#3    NA  NA  NA
#4    NA  NA  NA
#5    NA  NA  NA
#6    NA  NA  NA
#7    NA  NA  NA
#8    NA  NA  NA
#9    NA  NA  NA
#10   NA  NA  NA
#11   NA  NA  NA

df$Group <- Chunky4Loop(chunk = nGroups,
                         quantity = nPeople,
                         input = GroupName)
df
#   Group ATK DMG
#1      A  NA  NA
#2      A  NA  NA
#3      A  NA  NA
#4      A  NA  NA
#5      A  NA  NA
#6      A  NA  NA
#7      A  NA  NA
#8      B  NA  NA
#9      B  NA  NA
#10     B  NA  NA
#11     C  NA  NA
```

However, I have to run it over many variables, which is doable. I'd like to simplify it even further, though, by creating a vector of input variables, output columns, and then entering these two meta-variables into a For Loop like this:

```
    # I specify the original values contained within the arrays
    ATK <- c(7,3,1)
    DMG <- c(7,3,1) 
      
    # I create an array of the input variables I just specified ...
    inputs <- c('ATK', 'DMG')
    
    # Then I create an array of columns to output to ...
    outputs <- c('df$ATK', 'df$DMG')
      
    # Then I run the Chunky4Loop function to keep this all compacted
    for (i in 1:length(inputs)){
      outputs[i] <- Chunky4Loop(chunk = nGroups,
                                quantity = nPeople,
                                input = inputs[i])
     } # added missing close-curly-brace
```

I would ideally get this:

```
   Group ATK DMG
1      A  7   7
2      A  7   7
3      A  7   7
4      A  7   7
5      A  7   7
6      A  7   7
7      A  7   7
8      B  3   3
9      B  3   3
10     B  3   3
11     C  1   1
```

But R will not recognize these inputs or outputs and will produce the message:

```
In outputs[i] <- Chunky4Loop(chunk = nGroups, quantity = nPeople,  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Can I make this work?

Comment: After supplying the missing close-paren I don't get an error , I get a warning:  `Warning messages:
1: In outputs[i] <- Chunky4Loop(chunk = nGroups, quantity = nPeople,  :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length` So you should now do some debugging. (Learn to debug.) Add some `cat(str(...)` or some `print(...)` statements inside the body of that for loop. Or increase the sensitivity of the error detection and figure out what the loop index is when the warning occur.

Comment: This is NOT an array: `outputs <- c('df$ATK', 'df$DMG')`. It's going to be an atomic vector that is twice the length of the number of rows in `df`. If you wanted a dimensioned object for `outputs` it might be `outputs <- df[ , c('ATK', 'DMG')]`, but it would be a "data.frame" rather than an "array". (You will not be able to read the help pages unless you learn the specific "R meanings" of terms like "matrix", "array", and "data.frame".)